# Kotlin : Why is the size of a ByteArray different after conversion to a String?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing a Kotlin application on Android and for different reasons, I need to convert ByteArray to String and vice versa.
However, when I convert a ByteArray into a String and then return to a ByteArray, the size of the last ByteArray is different from that of the original ByteArray.

Here is my code:

```
private lateinit var sessionKey: ByteArray

private fun genSessionKey() {
    val r = SecureRandom()
    sessionKey = ByteArray(16)
    r.nextBytes(sessionKey)
    println("sessionkey size in genSessionKey() : ${sessionKey.size}")
    val sessionkeyInString = sessionKey.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
    println("sessionkey size in genSessionKey() after conversion : ${sessionkeyInString.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8).size}")
}
```

And here is what I have in output:

```
I/System.out: sessionkey size in genSessionKey() : 16
I/System.out: sessionkey size in genSessionKey() after conversion : 30
```

I guess it's a question of encoding but I'm not sure, what's my mistake?

Comment: In utf-8 strings characters are represented by 1 to 5 bytes each. Your byte array contain values different from ansi codes. All those different codes are converted to at least two bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of each byte in `sessionKey` can be any value from 0 to 255. When you then convert this to a `String` using UTF-8 encoding, you will get a `String` containing any number of characters (depending on how the random bytes map to the encoding). It is also possible that some of the byte sequences cannot be converted to characters in `String` at all, because not all byte sequences are valid UTF-8 characters.

Don't do this. This is not a reliable way to convert between byte values and `String`. If you need a string representation of a bunch of bytes then you should convert each one of them to 2-character hex values, like "0b" or "26" and create a `String` from that.

Comment: Ok I get it! Thank you for your help!

Comment: If this answer was helpful, you can "accept" it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer.